# How to use throws java.io.IOException?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

Below you can see my code. I am new to java (this is homework) and my question is, where I need to put throws java.io.IOException and how would look code if I need to input some text. Really hope that you understand my question. Thanks.

EDITED - Looks like I need Scanner, because I need input chance.

```
class cilindrs {            //object
    int augstums;
    double radiuss;   // variables
    float pi;
    String krasa;

    cilindrs (int a, double r, float p, String k){    //constructor
        augstums = a;
        radiuss = r;     
        pi = p;
        krasa = k;
    }

    double tilpums(){   
        return 2 * (pi * radiuss * radiuss) * augstums;
    }

    double tips() {      //method
        if (krasa == "sudraba") {
             System.out.println("Jaa");
        } else {  
            System.out.println("Nee");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
class majasdarbs4 {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        cilindrs A = new cilindrs(12, 2.5, 3, "zils"); 
        cilindrs B = new cilindrs(23, 4, 3, "sudraba");
        cilindrs C = new cilindrs (17, 9, 3, "melns");

        double V;

        V = A.tilpums();
        System.out.println("Tilpums ir " + V);

        System.out.println ("Izvelesimies so cilindru?  ");
        A.tips();

        V = B.tilpums();
        System.out.println("Tilpums ir " + V);

        System.out.println ("Izvelesimies so cilindru?  ");
        B.tips();

        V = C.tilpums();
        System.out.println("Tilpums ir " + V);

        System.out.println ("Izvelesimies so cilindru?  ");
        C.tips();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it getting input from?

Comment: Nothing in here throws an `IOException`, so I'm not sure what you want it for... Also, *please* format your code correctly.

Comment: You tried nothing, this is your homework, code is awfully formatted and doesn't even meet coding standards. And you just sit there, waiting for someone doing your homework. Well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOException signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations.

You should throw this after failed/wrong inputs, for example:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = in.next();

if (s.equals("bad")) {
throw new IOException("Wrong input");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to put `IOException` anywhere in that code. Besides you are waiting for a working solution to your homework.

Answer (score 1):

IoException required where input and output are used in process.

you don't use any input and output process. therefore there is no need of IoException.

Answer (score 1):

First sign the method that may throw an exception just before body block, something like

```
public byte[] readData()throws IOException{

}
```

then this mathod would throws an exception if it get faced with some error/exception, and note that you should throw the exception with `throw` keyword.

```
public byte[] readData()throws IOException{
//...
if(<<Error>>){throw new IOException("Error!");}
//...
}
```

always throw exception(s) where method should not have decision about the possible errors/exception, and just let the caller method/block has decision about the business.